# How can I put jQuery in <script> attribute?

Tags: jquery, stripe-payments

If i write the code like below, A button will be visible for stripe modal.

```
<script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_11a6LFgOQ9rZ3d54Qd0uBF8c"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Oyon Shop"
    data-description="Thank you for puchasing!"
    data-image="/img/demo.png"
    data-locale="auto">
</script>
```

My value of data-amount is `$('#amount').val()`. So i did the following way.

```
<script>
    $("<script>", {
      src:"https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js",
      class: "stripe-button",
      "data-key": "pk_test_11a6LFgOQ9rZ3d54Qd0uBF8c",
      "data-amount": $('#amount').val(),
      "data-name": "Oyon Shop",
      "data-description": "Thank you for puchasing!",
      "data-image": "/img/demo.png",
      "data-locale": "auto",
    }).appendTo("head");
</script>
```

But after that, the stripe payment button is not visible. Would you please help me to find the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do it using `appendTo` this way:

```
$("<script>", {
  src:"https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js",
  class: "stripe-button",
  "data-key": "pk_test_11a6LFgOQ9rZ3d54Qd0uBF8c",
  "data-amount": $('#amount').val(),
  "data-name": "Oyon Shop",
  "data-description": "Thank you for puchasing!",
  "data-image": "/img/demo.png",
  "data-locale": "auto",
}).appendTo("head");
```

Or using the traditional way:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js';
script.setAttribute('class', "stripe-button");
script.setAttribute("data-key", "pk_test_11a6LFgOQ9rZ3d54Qd0uBF8c");
script.setAttrubute("data-amount", document.querySelector('#amount').value);
script.setAttribute("data-name", "Oyon Shop");
script.setAttribute("data-description", "Thank you for puchasing!");
script.setAttribute("data-image", "/img/demo.png");
script.setAttribute("data-locale", "auto");

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: So, i have to write code like before:

<script>
    $("<script>", {
        src:"https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js",
        class: "stripe-button",
       "data-key": "pk_test_11a6LFgOQ9rZ3d54Qd0uBF8c",
       "data-amount": $('#amount').val(),
      "data-name": "Oyon Shop",
      "data-description": "Thank you for puchasing!",
      "data-image": "/img/demo.png",
      "data-locale": "auto",
  }).appendTo("head");
</script>

right ?

Comment: Yes i accept it. Thanks For the solution. Would you please help me on my another question ? @Praveen Kumar

Comment: @SalehAhmadOyon Tell me the URL if you have already posted it.

Comment: [Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970737/how-can-i-disable-stripe-button-from-the-beginning-and-enable-it-after-checked-t)

Comment: I write the code like below:

<script> $("<script>", { src:"checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js";, class: "stripe-button", "data-key": "pk_test_11a6LFgOQ9rZ3d54Qd0uBF8c", "data-amount": $('#amount').val(), "data-name": "Oyon Shop", "data-description": "Thank you for puchasing!", "data-image": "/img/demo.png", "data-locale": "auto", }).appendTo("head"); </script>

But The button isn't visible. Why it's not working ?

Comment: @SalehAhmadOyon Can you edit your question and update please? So that it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can ass attribute value in script tag like this, 
Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("script").attr("data-amount",$('#amount').val())
});
```

Comment: The request would have already sent to the stripe server, by then. This is totally wrong. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

- You can have this code

  ```
    $("script").attr("data-amount",$('#amount').val())
  ```

  inside your own user-defined method.
- **$('#amount').val()**  may not have value, by the time the .ready() method is called.
- So it makes sense to put it inside any functions you have defined , so you can have that in a place where you are sure that **$('#amount').val()** will have the desired value by then.

Comment: As I said in the previous comments, the request would have already sent to the stripe server, by the time you put `<script>` tag. This is totally wrong. Do you understand the consequences of it?